# Want to extract all images frame by frame in video while video is getting played in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, video, avplayer

Extract all images frame by frame in video while video is getting played in AVPlayer.

For example if video is 30 fps and video duration is 10 secs then I should be able to get 300 images from video.

Currently I am extracting images using this code:

[self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1, fps) queue:dispatch_get_main_queue() usingBlock:

```
^(CMTime time) {
    [weakSelf readNextMovieFrame];
}];
(void) readNextMovieFrame {

CMTime outputItemTime = [[self playerItem] currentTime];

CMTime t = [[self playerItem] currentTime];
CMTime d = [[self playerItem] duration];

if ([_output hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:outputItemTime]) {
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [_output copyPixelBufferForItemTime:outputItemTime itemTimeForDisplay:nil];

    CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:buffer];

    UIImage *imageUI = [self makeUIImageFromCIImage:image];

    [self saveImage];

    //CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    CVBufferRelease(buffer);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to extract an image from a video on iOS.

```
- (UIImage *)getVideoImageAtTime:(CMTime)time player:(AVPlayer *)player {
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAsset *asset = player.currentItem.asset;
    AVAssetImageGenerator *ig = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    CGImageRef image = [ig copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:nil error:&error];
    UIImage *screenShot = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
    CGImageRelease(image);
    return error ? screenShot : nil;
}
```